# Restrict jwt refresh token to only one endpoint

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

I have implemented JWT token authorization & authentication from Spring resource server dependency. Here is the config file:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${app.chat.jwt.public.key}")
    private RSAPublicKey publicKey;

    @Value("${app.chat.jwt.private.key}")
    private RSAPrivateKey privateKey;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.exceptionHandling(
                exceptions ->
                        exceptions
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                                .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler()));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/sign-in").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/sign-up").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        var jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).privateKey(privateKey).build();
        var jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(publicKey).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        var jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
                new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

It works fine. I have AuthController where I have implemented endpoints for sign-in, sign-up, and refresh token. In each endpoint, I return a response with an access token and a refresh token. Here is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {
    private final JwtTokenService tokenService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authManager;
    private final UserDetailsService usrDetailsService;

    private final UserService userService;



    record LoginRequest(String username, String password) {}
    @PostMapping("/sign-in")
    public TokensResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.username, request.password);
        authManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);

        var user = (User) usrDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.username);
        String accessToken = tokenService.generateAccessToken(user);
        String refreshToken = tokenService.generateRefreshToken(user);

        return new TokensResponse(accessToken, refreshToken);
    }

    record SignUpRequest(String username, String password){}

    @PostMapping("/sign-up")
    public TokensResponse signUp(@RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
        User registeredUser = userService.register(new AuthRequestDto(signUpRequest.username(), signUpRequest.password()));

        String accessToken = tokenService.generateAccessToken(registeredUser);
        String refreshToken = tokenService.generateRefreshToken(registeredUser);

        return new TokensResponse(accessToken, refreshToken);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('REFRESH_TOKEN')")
    @GetMapping("/token/refresh")
    public TokensResponse refreshToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String previousRefreshToken = headerAuth.substring(7);

        String username = tokenService.parseToken(previousRefreshToken);
        var user = (User) usrDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        String accessToken = tokenService.generateAccessToken(user);
        String refreshToken = tokenService.generateRefreshToken(user);

        return new TokensResponse(accessToken, refreshToken);
    }

    record TokensResponse(String accessToken, String refreshToken) {}

}
```

And here is TokenService class where I generate those tokens:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenServiceImpl implements JwtTokenService {

    private final JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;

    @Override
    public String generateAccessToken(User user) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = user.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
                .subject(user.getUsername())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();
        return this.jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }

    @Override
    public String generateRefreshToken(User user) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = "ROLE_REFRESH_TOKEN";

        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
                .subject(user.getUsername())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();
        return this.jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }

    @Override
    public String parseToken(String token) {
        try {
            SignedJWT decodedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(token);
            return decodedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to restrict the refresh token to be used only for the refresh endpoint. Because what's the point of having a short-term live access token if you can use a refresh token for all endpoints? I have tried to give the refresh token scope REFRESH_TOKEN and added `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('REFRESH_TOKEN')")` annotation for the refresh token endpoint. But it doesn't work(I can still send access token to refresh endpoint and get new tokens), because Spring doesn't look for claims from token. He just loads the user from the database by username from token and checks his roles from here.

Please suggest how can I make the refresh token restricted only to one endpoint. Also would be great to make him one-time use but seems that I would need to store tokens somewhere for that.

Comment: What is your version of Spring Boot?

Comment: @JamesGrey 3.0.0. I can upload a project to GitHub if needed.

Comment: You can upload to GitHub for more clear.

Comment: @JamesGrey here is link to repo https://github.com/EternalSadnes/chat-app

Comment: What is your "one endpoint" ?

Comment: @JamesGrey In AuthController I have /token/refresh endpoint. I want the refresh token to be accepted only in this endpoint and return 403 if it is used to access other endpoints

Comment: Add `.requestMatchers("/token/refresh").permitAll()`

Comment: @JamesGrey and what it changed? I still can send the access token to the refresh endpoint and the refresh token to the hello endpoint and it is accepted.

Comment: You expected maybe not feasibility. Because when refresh token will affect to all end-points.

Answer (score 1):

You can add "access" authority to every access token and make it mandatory for all endpoints except refresh token endpoint. Therefore refresh token will not have access to all enpoints.

TokenService class:

```
    @Override
    public String generateAccessToken(User user) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = user.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        String accessScope = scope.concat(" access");

        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
            .issuer("self")
            .issuedAt(now)
            .expiresAt(now.plus(2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
            .subject(user.getUsername())
            .claim("roles", accessScope)
            .build();
        ...
```

and WebSecurityConfig class:

```
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/auth/sign-in").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/auth/sign-up").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasAuthority("ROLE_access")
            .and()
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
```

BTW in WebSecurityConfig class you set claim name to "roles":

```
jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
```

but in JwtTokenServiceImpl class you use "claim" for claim name:

```
JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
            .issuer("self")
            .issuedAt(now)
            .expiresAt(now.plus(2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
            .subject(user.getUsername())
            .claim("scope", scope)
            .build();
```

I think you have to use one name everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
the refresh token is bound to the
   client to which it was issued.
```

source https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6

Refresh token affect to client scope (it means all end-points). Therefore your expected is not feasibility.

Comment: But then what's the point of having two tokens(access - short-lived and refresh - long-lived) if I can throw out a short-lived token and use just refresh token for all requests?